# Javascript get id number from a class name with parseint

Tags: javascript

Using Javascript, i am trying to extract a number from an element that looks like this

```js
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", function() {

  console.log("Button clicked")

  parent = this.parentNode;
  console.log(parent);

  value = parseInt(parent);
  console.log(value);

});
```

```css
#mybutton {
  padding: 20px;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="myelement myid-364444-number">
  <div id="mybutton">
    Button
  </div>
</div>
```

I am getting `NaN` everytime, where am I goind wrong?

Comment: you are treating the element as a number. Do you want to extract the number from the class name ?

Comment: parseInt of a DOM object.... not the class attribute

Comment: Yes, I am wanting to extract the number

Comment: What value are you seeing for console.log(parent)?

Comment: @Eric OP said `NaN` in the post. Also, run the code snippet and click on the button.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way, for this specific example is to use a regular expression on the `className` of the `parent` node.

```js
document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", function() {

  console.log("Button clicked")

  const parent = this.parentNode;
  console.log(parent);

  const value = parseInt(parent.className.match(/\d+/));
  console.log(value);

});
```

```css
#mybutton {
  padding: 20px;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="myelement myid-364444-number">
  <div id="mybutton">
    Button
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution works great, what if I wanted to extract all the numbers from this as an example myid-273YU322-number

Comment: I am thinking I could change the match to \\d+

Comment: @fightstarr20 use `parent.className.match( /\d+/g ).join( '' );` to get `273322` from `myid-273YU322-number`. Though the downside here is if any other class had numbers they'd be included. So the matching pattern would have to be improved.

Comment: @fightstarr20 would you want to receive two numbers or 273322